# How to change text cursor color in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, text-cursor

I have a text widget with dark background and I can't see the cursor's position. Is there any way to change the (blinking) text cursor's color?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can change the `insertbackground` option of the text widget to whatever you want.

Answer (score 17):

Option for text cursor color in Tk is `-insertbackground`.

```
textWidget.config(insertbackground=...)
```

Comment: Is there any way to change the thickness of the cursor ? Just like the default cursor in Vim?

Comment: @Jdeep Yes: "insertwidth".

Answer (score 3):

For python version 3

```
import tkinter as tk

textfield = tk.Entry(root)
textfield.configure(bg="#1C6C0B", insertbackground='white')
```