# how to change the mouse pointer color tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

is there a way to change the mouse color in Tkinter? I have a dark background and the mouse never shows over the Tkinter window.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the cursor using the [cursor option on the root window](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/cursors.html). To change the color, e.g.,

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.config(cursor='clock red red')
```

Some symbols and colors work for me, some don't, on linux, although the option should be operating system agnostic. For example, 'clock' and 'gumby' work, 'pirate' does not (but fails quietly, without throwing an error).

Ironically, boat is supported on my machine, but pirates are not. Probably a good call not to support both

**In response to comment**

Sometimes you need to call this on sub-widgets, if their default behaviour is to overwrite it. For example

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.config(cursor='gumby red red')
text=tk.Text(root)
text.pack()
# oh no cursor is boring again! That makes sense, the default
# text cursor is slightly different than the root cursor
text.config(cursor='boat blue blue') # phew!
```

Note that if instead you wanted to change the insertion cursor, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284492/how-to-change-text-cursor-color-in-tkinter), but tldr `insertbackground`. Note that you may be using a cursor that doesn't support changing colors, in which case try a different cursor

Comment: what about the text cursor? I tried this and the cursor is still black and I think it is because it is not a mouse pointer but the text cursor.  When the mouse is over the text widget, the mouse is still black.

Comment: @Jleong that better? make sure the cursor you're changing it to supports multiple colors (boat is a good guess to test that)

Comment: thanks! it worked perfectly!  just a quick question, how would you change it to the default cursor?

Comment: No problem (you're able to "accept" an answer if you'd like to, though you're entitled not to or to hold off for other answers). The link in the answer covers most of the available cursors; "xterm" is the default for my text widget, 'left_ptr' looks like my default on root. Don't know if those have avaliable alternate colors. You can use widget.config('cursor') to get the current settings for the cursor if you want to apply it later,though this may be empty if its not set. For text it should say 'xterm'