# Tkinter mouse color

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, colors, mouse-cursor

I'm working on a project right now, and I need to get a black mouse cursor like this:

[image]

I've used `root.config(cursor="arrow black black")`, but it doesnt want to change the color of the cursor. I'm using windows, and if this helps, Windows has the black cursor installed by default.

Can anyone help me on this?

### Edit:

[how to change the mouse pointer color tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35757296/how-to-change-the-mouse-pointer-color-tkinter) does not work for me.

I can change how the cursor looks, but not the color.

Comment: I've also used `root.config(cursor="arrow #000000")` and it doesnt work.

Comment: What platform? My research yields that on OSX or Windows the color may not be configurable.

Comment: windows 7 is my os

Comment: Much like other visuals in Tkinter the mouse curse probably inherits its theme directly from windows. As such it likely has features that cannot be changed. I do know that you can write custom widgets like a customer scroll bar but I am not sure you can do the same for a mouse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change the mouse pointer color tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35757296/how-to-change-the-mouse-pointer-color-tkinter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows systems, the `arrow` pointer is mapped to native [`IDC_ARROW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms648070.aspx) pointer, the color of which you can't control within `tkinter`.

Of course, Windows does have a black mouse pointer, but appearance of the pointer in use depends on the current color scheme (Control panel - Mouse - Pointer), so you wouldn't see it unless you'd changed the scheme.
Applications should not touch it, since it's strictly a user preference.

However, the black pointer file lives at `%windir%\Cursors\arrow_r.cur`, so we can use it directly when needed:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

root = tk.Tk()
path = '@%s' % os.path.join(os.environ['WINDIR'], 'Cursors/arrow_r.cur').replace('\\', '/')

root.configure(cursor=path)
root.mainloop()
```

It's also worth to notice, that the black pointer has a medium and a large variants - `arrow_rm.cur` and `arrow_rl.cur` respectively.