# How to add custom image to cursor when hovered over python tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, mouse-cursor

I want to make a custom image cursor when the cursor is hovered over my tkinter window, something like this:

[image: Black cursor]

However, no matter how hard I google, I cannot find out how to add a custom cursor to my tkinter window, so I'm stuck with the default white cursor.

[image: Default cursor]

Is there anyway I can add a custom image to my cursor when it is hovered over my tkinter window?

Comment: Hello, I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338888/tkinter-mouse-color) is going to help you. Keep in mind that applications follow the user theme setup in windows.

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61459143/python-tkinter-how-can-i-set-the-cursor-as-an-image)

Comment: @AST Yes, that answers my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you have a custom image with you already and it is a .cur file, if not, it should either be `cur` or `ani` or `xbm` files, which are the only supported cursor extensions. Once you have the file, you can specify it by using the `cursor` option of main window, like:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
path = '@Norm.ani' # Path to the image followed by @
root['cursor'] = path # Set the cursor 

Button(root,text='Anything').pack(padx=10,pady=10) # Demo button to show cursor

root.mainloop()
```

This applies the cursor to the entire window, though there are widgets to which custom cursors does not apply like `Menu`.

If you want custom cursor for just one widget, then use the cursor option of that widget, like:

```
Button(root,text='Anything',cursor=path).pack(padx=10,pady=10) # Applies JUST to button
```

**Why do we use '@'?**

From the docs:

> "In place of a standard bitmap name, use the string '@' followed by the path name of the .xbm file.".

In your case the `ani` or `cur` file.