# How to change the Text Cursor color in TTKBOOTSTRAP in Python for an Entry widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, cursor

I am trying to change the color of the text cursor in python using ttkbootstrap.

My end goal is to create an Entry widget whose background is white - this I succeeded; however, the text cursor is "white-ish" and thus I cannot see it.

This is what I have

```py
import ttkbootstrap as tb
import a_module_I_created as tkb

class Window_main:

   def __init__(self, root):

        ''' a bunch of code, this is unimportant'''

        self.table_t1_frame = tb.Frame(self.tab1)
        self.table_t1_frame.grid(row=0, column=6, rowspan=10, padx=25)
        self.table = tkb.Table_tab1(self.table_t1_frame)

root = tb.Window(themename='superhero')
app = Window_main(root)


app.root.mainloop()
```

On my table, the one that I defined as Table_tab1 I have this:

```py
table_entry_style = tb.Style("litera")
table_entry_style.configure('litera.TEntry', fieldbackground= 'white', foreground='black', insertbackground="black")

        ''' a bunch of code unimportant'''

self.entry[counter] = tb.Entry(frame, style="litera.TEntry", width=10)
self.entry[counter].grid(row=rows, column= col)
```

Here is a screenshot of the table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCQ95.png)

It "works" as in, it changes the background of the Entry widget to white and the text to black. However, the text cursor is "white" so I cannot see which Entry box am I going to type into until I actually type.

As you can see I already tried `insertbackground` and it was suggested below

[How to change text cursor color in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284492/how-to-change-text-cursor-color-in-tkinter)

How can I change the color of the text cursor to something "dark" so I can see it?

I have tried many methods, such as changing the "style" to litera (only the widget's style since I want to keep the theme "superhero" for the rest of the app) but it did not work.

I tried using other styles colors like "success", "light", "primary" etc. inside configure using configure(theme_use="success") etc. but it did not work.

My guess is that the main theme "superhero" is overwriting everything.

Can somebody help me?

This is the link to the ttkbootstrap documentation https://ttkbootstrap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/themes/light/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ttk styling option for the cursor is `insertcolor`.

I don't have ttkbootstrap installed, but I'm guessing this should work:

```
table_entry_style.configure('litera.TEntry', ..., insertcolor="black")
#                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```